# How to create desktop.ini in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, desktop.ini

My goal is to customize all folder icon if the foder's name end by "_S"
So i writed a PowerShell function but the customize doesn't work.

I took inspiration from: 
[Website to set attribute on desktop.ini](https://morgansimonsen.com/2012/02/21/desktop-ini-customizations-do-not-take-effect/)
[Function that sets a custom folder icon](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-FolderIcon-0bd56629)

```
function Set-icon_Folder_S($path) 
{

$ini = '[.ShellClassInfo]
        IconIndex =  0
        IconResource=C:\private.ico,0
        ConfirmFileOp = 0       
        DefaultDropEffect = 1'


    Set-Location $path
    #List all folder end with _S
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.Attributes -match "Directory") -and ($_.Name.EndsWith("_S"))} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

    #For each folder _S ...
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        Set-Location $item

        #Init. Delete desktop.ini if exist
        try {
            Remove-Item desktop.ini -Force -erroraction stop
        }
        catch {         
        }

        #Write desktop.ini
        Write-Host "Go to $($item)"
        $ini | Out-File desktop.ini -Force
        Set-ItemProperty desktop.ini -Name Attributes -Value “ReadOnly,System,Hidden”

    }
}
```

I doesn't find error.

Comment: I added Archive Property and deleted ReadOnly, but does'nt works. The folder icon doesn't has change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following adjusted script works for me: adding an empty-line to `desktop.ini` tail should do the trick in itself (calling `attrib.exe` I have tried first so it *might be superabundant*):

```
function Set-icon_Folder_S($path) 
{
$ini = '[.ShellClassInfo]
        IconIndex =  0
        IconResource=D:\Remote\icons\folderBlue.ico,0
        ConfirmFileOp = 0       
        DefaultDropEffect = 1
        '                          ### empty line: important

    Push-Location "$path"          ### Push-Location instead of Set-Location
    #List all folder end with _S
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
        Where-Object {
          ($_.Attributes -match "Directory") -and ($_.Name.EndsWith("es"))} | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName                   ### ↑↑  change!!!

    #For each folder _S ...
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        Push-Location "$item"      ### Push-Location instead of Set-Location

        #Init. Delete desktop.ini if exist
        try {
            Remove-Item desktop.ini -Force -erroraction stop
        }
        catch {                    ### Write-Host "error removing $($item)"
        }

        #Write desktop.ini
        Write-Host "Go to $($item)"
        $ini | Out-File desktop.ini -Force
        Set-ItemProperty desktop.ini -Name Attributes -Value “ReadOnly,System,Hidden”
        Pop-Location               ### Pop-Location for corresponding Push-Location
        attrib.exe +R +S "$item"   ### Follow DESKTOP.INI CUSTOMIZATIONS DO NOT …
    }
    Pop-Location                   ### Pop-Location for corresponding Push-Location
}

Set-icon_Folder_S "D:\PShell"      ### call function declared above
```

Changes are described in above code using ### comments (**except** `IconResource`):

```
### another IconResource used to match my testing environment
### empty line: important
### Push-Location instead of Set-Location
### used `"es"` suffix instead of `"_S"` one to match my testing environment
### Pop-Location for corresponding Push-Location
attrib.exe +R +S "$item"           ### Follow DESKTOP.INI CUSTOMIZATIONS DO NOT TAKE EFFECT
Set-icon_Folder_S "D:\PShell"      ### call function declared above
```

Comment: Interesting. Why `Push-Location` instead of `Set-Location`?